# What difference of Click and Focus() in TextBox class netCF?

Tags: c#, focus, windows-ce

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            textBox2.Focus();
    }

    private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            CursorTest();

    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CursorTest();
    }


    private void CursorTest()
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(i.ToString());

        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;

    }
```

case 1 : I click button4, - CursorTest() show waitcursor

case 2 : I input 'ENTER' on textBox1 and move focus to textBox2

and input again 'ENTER' on textBox2 - CursorText() doesn't appear waitcursor.

case 3 : I just click textBox2 and input 'ENTER' - CursorText() appear waitcursor.

How do i show the Wait-Cursor in all cases?
What is the difference of Click and Focus()?

Comment: Does your programm call the CursorTest Function? You have to think about your For-loop too. A WaitCursor for 100 loopruns is less than a milisecond long on a standart machine.

Comment: yes. my program call 'CursorTest()', and 'CursorTest()' spent about 5sec. CursorTest is just simple test function. real function is more spent time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the TextBox.TextChanged Event and call `CursorTest()` from there. That will work.

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CursorTest();
    }
```